# Localic group as generalizations of topological groups

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, algebraic-topology, heyting-algebra, locales

I have read about what locales and frames are (basic objects in pointfree topology) and now I'be seen that there exists localic groups as a generalization of topological groups. I have some questions:

- On which objects are groups are acting upon?
- What are the most important properties of localic groups?
- When will these localic groups be used?

Moreover I would appreciate if someone would give some references for this topic.